# Ссылки на LinkedIn в подвале страницы

Tags: обсуждение

Вопрос скорее из любопытства, из каких соображений на всех страницах RU версии присутствуют ссылки на LinkedIn ? Мало того что оно запрещено на территории РФ, как игил :) так оно ещё и является откровенной спам помойкой. Это конечно личное мнение, но глаз режет эта ссылка.

Особенно в свете новости покупки Github Microsoft'ом..
Судьба вероятно будет такая же как и у LinkedIn..

Comment: шаблон одинаковый для всех сайтов сети: данные ссылки показывают присутствие компании (SO) в соцсетях. Никакого специального умысла _давайте для ruSO добавим linkedIn_ очевидно не было.

Comment: Ссылка в подвале режет глаза? Вы серьёзно? Я этот подвал забыл, когда видел, не долистываю.

Comment: Русскоязычная версия сайта - это русскоязычная, а не российская версия сайта. Ей пользуются пользователи других стран СНГ, в которых с LinkedIn всё в порядке.

Comment: На всякий случай - Stack Overflow работает опенсорсовом ASP.NET MVC от MS, так что вы последние N лет регулярно наслаждаетесь вкладом MS в опенсорс.

Comment: Спасибо за минусы, ожидаемо :) не ошибся, отлично! :)

Comment: @PashaPash, Микрософт гораздо более унес из OpenSource, чем принёс, включая историю создания. Но об этом 'неприлично' вспоминать в 'элитных кругах' адептов :)

Comment: @NewView если у вас есть предвзятость к любой компании - MS (который 20 лет назад что-то уносил из опенсорса), гугл (который кучу проектов купил и закрыл), Oracle (кровавый энтерпрайз, посмотрите что он с Sun сотворил) или даже к Atlassian (который превратили мой любимый bitbucket в тормозное нечто) - это ваши личные проблемы. Не стоит вытягивать это на мету SO, и тем более не стоит переходить на стиль общения вида "элитные круги адептов".

Comment: @PashaPash, покорно умолкаю.. :) про Орак и Гугл - обсолютно солидарен +

Comment: LinkedIn запрещён, т.к. не захотел хранить данные российских пользователях на серверах в России. Что за вбросы про "игил"?

Comment: Что за бред?! У меня в гостях был друг, так он подобный бред нес, а когда я наконец-то выяснил источник, то все стало ясно. Новости, особенно политические, вот это настоящее зло и не важно в какой это стране. Никогда не понимал, зачем люди софт привязывают к политике? Скорее всего для самопиара, или пиара той самой политики, но это лишь предположение. Лучше бы эту энергию, люди направляли на создание чего-то полезного. Там где политика или религия - там эмоции, а там где эмоции способность рассуждать трезво - отключается.

Answer (score 0):

С чего американскую компанию должно заботить безумие российских властей?
Если так уж припрёт и им придёт уведомление от РосКомПозора, то они **могут** пойти навстречу только из-за части аудитории.

Пока что, очевидно, подобных запросов нет и всем до лампочки.

---

Если Вы из РФ, то Вы не должны даже пытаться переходить по еретической ссылке, не одобренной Свыше, а если просто русскоговорящий из другой страны - для Вас ссылка будет и Вы сможете найти компанию, вместо лишнего гугления.

P. S. Про "глаз режет" Вы, конечно, сильно сказали, согласен с товарищем [@vp_arth](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7418/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-linkedin-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/7419#comment30387_7418).

Comment: Некоторые ресурсы, на которые есть ссылка на странице, у некоторой части населения вызывают ту реакцию которую вызывают :) гражданство и росссвязьнадзор к этому не имеют никакого отношения. Извените что задел вопрос религиозного отношения к ресурсам микрософт :)

Comment: Извините, но это какой-то бред. "Они вызывают то, что вызывают" - смысл в чём? И при чём тут вообще мелкомягкие?